# Execution time for each test case

Tags: catch2

I have a huge number of test cases which were written in C++. There is a time limit for the whole test cases. Because of large number of test cases timeout happened during testing. I would like to know the spending time for each test case so I can do some refactoring to those specific test cases for better running time. Unfortunately I could not find suitable solution in Catch2 framework. If you have any idea or solution, I would like to know

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [durations](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/command-line.md#reporting-timings) command line option.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword you are looking for is BENCHMARK. It is a bit poorly documented, but you can find samples here https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/projects/SelfTest/UsageTests/Benchmark.tests.cpp

Comment: For future searchers:
Documentation for it can be found in Catch2/docs/benchmarks.md in your Catch2.0 branch
Now it's https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/benchmarks.md